# Data is not getting fetched when status is Pending in PLSQL

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to download an excel report based on `State` and `Status`. And for getting that data I am calling an SP whose query is below

```
SELECT * FROM UBR_STRUCTURE_DETAILS WHERE (STATE = P_STATE) AND (NE_STATUS = P_STATUS);
```

there are lot's of data for the query but I am not getting a single record.

State -> Maharashtra

Status -> Pending.

**NOTE**  IF status is pending the value in `UBR_STRUCTURE_DETAILS` for status column is `''`

**update**

```
PROCEDURE GET_DATA_WITH_STATUS_EXL
 (
   P_STATE NVARCHAR2,
   P_STATUS VARCHAR2,
   TBL_STATE_REP OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
 )
AS
   BEGIN
  OPEN TBL_STATE_REP FOR 
       SELECT * FROM UBR_STRUCTURE_DETAILS WHERE (STATE = P_STATE) AND (NE_STATUS = P_STATUS);
    NULL;
END  GET_DATA_WITH_STATUS_EXL;
```

Comment: did you tried to add `or NE_STATUS = P_STATUS` to the query?

Comment: @droidnation: cant add `or` because i want both condition to satisfy

Comment: can you add some screenshots or at least make an SQL fiddle ?

Comment: @droidnation:updated the question,Do let me know if you have any other doubts

Comment: In the query you used `AND`, in your updated script you are using `OR`

Comment: @droidnation: sorry, i was checking the query with `OR`. Now updated it as earlier it was

Comment: try this `SELECT * FROM UBR_STRUCTURE_DETAILS WHERE (STATE = P_STATE) AND (NE_STATUS = P_STATUS or NE_STATUS = '');`. You are saying that if pending, the NE_STATUS is null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154124/discussion-between-vvvv-and-droidnation).

Comment: Are you using ORACLE or MYSQL?

Comment: @etsa: I am using `PLSQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
PROCEDURE GET_DATA_WITH_STATUS_EXL
 (
   P_STATE NVARCHAR2,
   P_STATUS VARCHAR2,
   TBL_STATE_REP OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
 )
AS
   BEGIN
       OPEN TBL_STATE_REP FOR 
       SELECT * FROM UBR_STRUCTURE_DETAILS 
       WHERE (STATE = P_STATE) AND (NE_STATUS = P_STATUS OR P_STATUS = 'Pending' AND NE_STATUS IS NULL);
    NULL;
END  GET_DATA_WITH_STATUS_EXL;
```

Simulation for xing, who had some doubts:

```
CREATE TABLE T_R (ID NUMBER(5,0), NE_STATUS VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO T_R VALUES (1,'Pending');
INSERT INTO T_R VALUES (2,'Not Pending');
INSERT INTO T_R VALUES (3,NULL);
INSERT INTO T_R VALUES (4,'');
```

Extract Pending

```
SELECT * FROM T_R
WHERE NE_STATUS = 'Pending' OR 'Pending' = 'Pending' AND NE_STATUS IS NULL;
```

Output:

```
1   Pending
3   (null)
4   (null)
```

Extract Others

```
SELECT * FROM T_R
WHERE NE_STATUS = 'Not Pending' OR 'Not_Pending' = 'Pending' AND NE_STATUS IS NULL;
```

Output:

```
2   Not Pending
```

Comment: This won;t get you correct result. It will only get Pending records not other. And clause will block it

Comment: @Xing: Example?

Comment: `NE_STATUS = P_STATUS OR P_STATUS = 'Pending' AND NE_STATUS IS NULL);` What would this do ? Check if that matches the requirement  . OP said, only when status='Pending' the staus col in table would be null

Comment: Only incase when `P_STATUS = 'Pending' AND NE_STATUS IS NULL` ..Not in all case

Comment: When P_STATUS <> 'Pending' will act NE_STATUS=P_STATUS.

Comment: @etsa: hi, are you their ?

Answer (score 1):

In SP your query look like this

```
SELECT * FROM UBR_STRUCTURE_DETAILS WHERE (STATE = @P_STATE) AND (NE_STATUS = @P_STATUS)
```

You have to pass a value to parameter in sqlcomman object.

For example:

```
sqlcomman.parameter.add("@P_STATE",stringState);
```

Comment: I am not using `sql`. I am using plsql. here the way of using parameter is different

Answer (score 1):

The one possibilty i can see if `CASE` and `SPACE` when you put the joining condition. I would say to convert the input string and table column to same case and trim the spaces while doing a match. See below:

> NOTE IF status is pending the value in UBR_STRUCTURE_DETAILS for
>   status column is ''

```
PROCEDURE GET_DATA_WITH_STATUS_EXL (P_STATE             NVARCHAR2,
                                    P_STATUS            VARCHAR2,
                                    TBL_STATE_REP   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN TBL_STATE_REP FOR
      SELECT *
        FROM UBR_STRUCTURE_DETAILS
       WHERE     DECODE (NE_STATUS, NULL, 'Y', TRIM (LOWER (NE_STATUS))) =                        CASE
                       WHEN INITCAP (P_STATUS) = 'Pending' THEN 'Y'
                       ELSE TRIM (LOWER (P_STATUS))
                    END
             AND TRIM (LOWER (STATE)) = TRIM (LOWER (P_STATE));
-- NULL;
END GET_DATA_WITH_STATUS_EXL;
```

Comment: will try and check this, may be this can help

Comment: `' '` is still not working but `IS NULL` is working. how to add that `IS NULL` in query ?

Comment: not working, i guess it should be `IS NULL` ? still no data in excel

Comment: @VVVV  `i guess it should be IS NULL` Are you getting syntax error when you run the `Proc`. If not then whatever is suggested above is correct syntactical.  Can you tell what you get when you do `Select NE_STATUS from UBR_STRUCTURE_DETAILS where initcap(P_STATUS) = 'Pending'`

Comment: it comes blank.. no record

Comment: hi XING, are you their ? do let me know once u come.

Comment: @VVVV. Did you try what i suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154203/discussion-between-vvvv-and-xing).

Comment: @VVVV. You already mentioned that the above solution by etsa is working for you, What else you want to discuss. Also chats are blocked here

Comment: if you come on chat for a sec, there I can explain you better, if you dont mind

Comment: chats are blocked here/ Am sorry.

Comment: ok. see, now i want one more column from another `child` table whose name is `UBR_EQUIPMENT_DETAILS`. so how should I get in my above query

Comment: ok. I am upvoting your answer. but i am accepting the `esta's` answer as it was correct and accurate. Thanks for the help